# adding another excel file values to the first empty cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel table with some amount of column and 100 rows.

```
  Sub GetFile()
 Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
 fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files       (*.XLSM), *.XLSM", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
  If fNameAndPath = False Then
  Exit Sub
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=fNameAndPath
End Sub
```

This code lets me open another xlsm file and i would like to add the rows of this opened Excel file to my master file. I would like to be able to add other Excel files as well, so vba code should understand which row is empty, so i can add it after the first empty row.

What should i do for this?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you find the next empty row:

```
With Sheets("Data")

 NextRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row+1

 .Range("B" &  NextRow) = TextBox1.Value
End With
```

reference: [find next empty space](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/360774-visual-basic-applications-finding-next-empty-row.html)

Comment: Have you had a chance to test out the solution?

Comment: i ll try it today and let you know:)